# Is the span of rationally independent real numbers dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define the subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ to be equal to $\{a_1\mathbb{Z} + a_2\mathbb{Z} +\cdots+ a_n\mathbb{Z} \}$, where $a_1,a_2\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ are rationally independent and $2\leq n<\infty$ is an arbitrary index. Is $S$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I believe it is true: what does a non-dense subgroup looks like ? What would this imply on the $a_i$'s ?

Comment: Is $n\ge2$ too right?

Comment: Very good point I have added it to the definition. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Okay, now use the fact that at least one of the two numbers is not in $\mathbb{Q}$ hence it's fractional part is infinitely periodic...

Comment: Can you generalize this to the case of $n-$rationally independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$, where $n\geq 2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subgroup of $\mathbb R$ is either dense or of the form $a\cdot\mathbb Z$ (this is a classical result):

If $S = \{0\}$, then $S = 0 \cdot \mathbb Z$ and we are done.

Otherwise, $S$ contains some $x \neq 0$ and so $\pm x > 0$ and so $S \cap(0, \infty) \neq \emptyset $. Set $a := \inf \left(S \cap (0, \infty)\right)$.

We have that $a \in S$ necessarily. Assume $a \notin S$, and so $a > 0$. There is then a sequence $x_n\in S$ converging to $a$, so $x_n-x_{n+1}$ converges to $0$ so $a=0$. Contradiction.

Now, if $a = 0$, you can see that $S$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Otherwise, the Eucledian division theorem says that if $x\in S$, $x=n\cdot a + r$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $0\leq r < a$. But $r=x-n\cdot a\in S$ so $r=0$ (because $a$ is the smallest positive element of $S$), and $x\in a\cdot \mathbb Z$, hence $S=a\cdot \mathbb Z$.

Coming back to the asked question, if $S$ is not dense, there is $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $S=a\cdot\mathbb Z$.

This implies that $a_1=na$ and $a_2=ma$ for some $n$ and $m$, hence $a_1/a_2=n/m$ so this contradicts the fact that they are rationnaly independent.

Comment: Would you mind giving the proof of that fact here?

Comment: Let $a=inf\{x\in S\cap \mathbb R_+^*\}$. If $a\notin S$, there is a sequence in $S$ converging to $a$ (because it is the inf) so in particular it is a Cauchy sequence, so one can see that (since $S$ is a subgroup), there are elements of $S$ as close to $0$ as we want, so $a=0$ and $S$ is dense.

Otherwise, $a\in S$ and it is easy to check that $S=a\cdot\mathbb Z$, using Euclidean division (if $x\in S$, $x=na+r$ with $0\leq r<a$ but $r=x-na\in S$ so $r=0$ because there are nopositive  elements of $S$ smaller than $a$).

Comment: Thank you. You could add that to your answer, so that everybody sees it right away.